# How to get Safari back in iOS6 on iPod Touch?

Tags: safari, ipod-touch, ios

I have an 4th Generation iPod Touch, running on iOS 6.0 and my Safari has vanished.

Regression:

- It is not shown on the home screen
- When I try to tap links to web pages, they only become highlighted (as they should), showing I am tapping them, and when I take my finger off the screen, nothing happens.
- When I try to search for things (For example, tree) on the search page on the home screen, there is no 'Search Safari for tree.' It does not come up with 'Search Wikipedia for tree.' either
- I have tried fully restoring my device, which did not work also

Answer (score 4):

Check the settings under **General > Restrictions**. If Safari is disabled there, it vanishes from the UI altogether.